# Getting href attribute value with jquery

Tags: jquery

A link of mine may look like:

```
<a href="/some/where?id=123">click</a>
```

When the link is clicked, my handler is triggered:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var hrefAttribute = $(this).attr("href"); // "/some/where?id=123"

   console.log(hrefAttribute);
});
```

hrefAttribute contains "/some/where?id=123".

What I would like, is to extract the value of the parameter called id. Hence the value "123"

As more attributes may be added to the url over time, I prefer not to extract the parameter value by string manipulation. A JQuery select value by parameter name would be better if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to obtain the `123` without some string manipulation of the `href` attribute.  You can, however, design that string manipulation so that it will still work even if other query arguments are added to the `href`.

For example, you could use a general purpose function for extracting a query parameter from a URL like this:

```
// returns the query argument for the given key or undefined if the key is not found
function getParam(url, key) {
    var regex = new RegExp("\\?.*?" + key + "=" + "(.*?)(&|$)");
    var matches = url.match(regex);
    if (matches) {
        return matches[1];
    }
}

var id = getParam(this.href, "id");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3uxwe2ce/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to extract the `id` as follows:

```
var hrefAttribute = $(this).attr("href"),
    id = hrefAttribute.replace(/^*id=(\d+)\b.*$/g,'$1');

console.log( id );
```

```js
$(document).on("click", "a", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var hrefAttribute = $(this).attr("href"),
       id = hrefAttribute.replace(/^.*id=(\d+)\b.*$/g,'$1');

   console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/some/where?jsd=5567&id=123">click</a>
When the link is clicked, my handler is triggered:
```

Another approach would be to use the `.forEach()` array method:

```
function getQParam(url, param) {
    var oParam = {};
    url.indexOf('?') === 0 || url.split('?')[1].split('&').forEach(function(v) {
        oParam[ v.split('=')[0] ] = v.split('=')[1];
    });
    return oParam[ param ];
}

var id = getQParam( this.href, 'id' );
```

```js
function getQParam(url, param) {
        var oParam = {};
        url.indexOf('?') === 0 || url.split('?')[1].split('&').forEach(function(v) {
            oParam[ v.split('=')[0] ] = v.split('=')[1];
        });
        return oParam[ param ];
    }
$(document).on("click", "a", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
    var id = getQParam( this.href, 'id' );
  console.log( id );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a href="/some/where?id=123">click</a>
    When the link is clicked, my handler is triggered:
```

Comment: Better check that regex.  Last I checked, `$` was the end of the string.

Comment: This has issues (e.g. doesn't work properly) when the id parameter isn't the first query parameter.  See test bed: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jhL0xxd0/

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$(this).attr("href", "/some/where?id=123");
```

If you want to put a dynamic URL you have to use $.ajax()